# Getting the selected values in a multiselect tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
function searchFlights() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("airports-select-1");
    var selected1 = [];
    while(select1.selectedIndex != -1) {
      if(select1.selectedIndex != 0) selected1.push(select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].value); 
      select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].selected = false;
   }

   console.log(selected1);
}
```

This works right, but as you can see from the code this line:

```
select1.options[select1.selectedIndex].selected = false;
```

Is doing a deselecting of the value.

Now, I do not want to deselect the values. If I uncomment that line in the code, the code will run forever.

Is there any more refined and sophisticated solution for retrieving multiple values from a select tag using Javascript?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Wouldn't this do it:

```
function searchFlights() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("airports-select-1");
    var selected1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++) {
        if (select1.options[i].selected) selected1.push(select1.options[i].value);
    }
    console.log(selected1);
}​
```

```js
function searchFlights() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("airports-select-1");
    var selected1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < select1.length; i++) {
        if (select1.options[i].selected) selected1.push(select1.options[i].value);
    }
    console.log(selected1);
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <select name="Select1" multiple="multiple" size="8" id="airports-select-1" onblur="searchFlights()" ;>
    <option>aaa</option>
    <option>bbb</option>
    <option>ccc</option>
    <option>ddd</option>
    <option>eee</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pQD8g/)**

Comment: @Adam Leggett's Update for 2018 is incredibly simple and works great

Answer (score 9):

Update for 2018:

- If the `<select>` element contains a `selectedOptions` property, use that collection. The only browser still in wide circulation that doesn't support this is IE (any version). Edge does support it.
- If this is not supported, the answer by @j08691 is still correct, but as a performance optimization you can start iterating options at `selectedIndex` instead of `0`. This is the index of the first selected option, or `-1` if nothing is selected.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach for those who like a more functional style:

```
selections = Array.from(selectBox.options).filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)
```

or

```
selections = Array.from(selectBox.selectedOptions).map(o => o.value)
```

Comment: I'm using `Object.values` instead of `Array.from`. Not sure if there's a difference though.