# Fetching the selected options html from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an select dropdown. I want to fetch the html of the selected option

```
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
</select>
```

For example if I select Yes and No I want the output as

```
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
```

Comment: How do you want to output it? In the console?

Comment: If you use it in a form, give the select tag a name attribute. With JS you can use select.selectedIndex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `ECMAScript` very easily.

```js
let select = document.getElementById('filter');

select.addEventListener('change', event => {
  let checkedOption = [...event.target.children].find(c => c.selected);
  console.log(checkedOption.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the help I have tried lot of options but didn;t succeed. Your answer saved me.

Comment: Hi @daemon if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fun(e){
var concat='';
for(var i = 0; i<e.children.length; i++)
{
 var str = e.children[i].outerHTML
 concat +=str;
}
console.log(concat);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple" onChange='fun(this)'>
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output in the console, here you go. No jQuery necessary.

```js
filter.addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log([...this.querySelectorAll(':checked')]);
  // even simpler but not available in IE 11:
  console.log([...filter.selectedOptions]);
})
```

```html
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>
```

If what you want is the values from those items which are selected, simply ask the `:checked` elements for their `textContent`:

```js
filter.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  console.log([...filter.querySelectorAll(':checked')].map(i=>i.textContent));
})
```

```html
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Yes</option>
  <option>No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using jQuery like this.

```js
$("#filter").on('change', function(){
  // the next line will find all the options which are selected
  options = $(this).find('option:selected');
  
  // loop through all the selected options and print them to console
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    option = options[i];
    console.log(option.outerHTML);
  }

});
```

```css
select{
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter" multiple="multiple">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question in [Getting the selected values in a multiselect tag in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11583728/getting-the-selected-values-in-a-multiselect-tag-in-javascript)

You can find selected OPTION elements by using `element.selected` command. In short, the function for finding these HTML elements would be something like this:

```
var list = document.getElementById("filter");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    if(list.options[i].selected) {
        console.log(list.options[i]);
    };
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bgz2cr9w/

Answer (score 0):

```
Using jquery you can get your desired output.


$(document).on('change', '#filter', function(){
    $.each($(this).find('option:selected'), function(i,d){
        console.log(d);
    })
});
```